# sql Percentile using percent rank()

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY convert(average_pan_score, decimal) desc) as rnk from (select *,percent_rank() OVER (ORDER BY convert(average_pan_score, decimal) ASC ) AS 'final_rank' from iot_athlete_ind_cont_non_cur_chlng_multiple_result WHERE aicid_id = 408) as a ORDER BY convert(average_pan_score, decimal) DESC;
```

```
INSERT INTO `iot_athlete_ind_cont_non_cur_chlng_multiple_result` (`m_id`, `athelte_id`, `attempt_no`, `aicid_id`, `average_pan_score`, `final_pan_score`, `final_pan_percentile`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(53, 116, '1', 408, '19', '18.75', 13, '2023-05-02 10:56:19', '2023-05-02 10:56:19'),
(54, 116, '1', 408, '19', '18.75', 13, '2023-05-02 10:56:19', '2023-05-02 10:56:19');
```

what is wrong with my query I am calculating the percentile based on average_pan_score.But According to the query it is showing 00.it should be 100.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKMik.png)

percentile using sql percent rank

expected result--->>

| average_pan_score | final_rank |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | 100 |
| 19 | 100 |